# Use hasOwnProperty with dot notation

Tags: javascript

I have one object `var tree={}` with attribute `tree.leaves.leaf={}`.
When I perform `tree.hasOwnProperty("leaves.leaf")` its giving `false` .
Can I use dot function inside `hasOwnProperty()` function? How to do it?

Comment: You can't, but you can do `tree.hasOwnProperty("leaves") && tree.leaves.hasOwnProperty("leaf")`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) which has a special function for searching all nested properties: `_.get([object], '[property]');`, which in your case would look like this: `_.get(tree, 'leaf')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like below

```
    var tree = {}
    tree["leaves"]={}
    tree["leaves"]['leaf'] = {}
    tree.leaves.hasOwnProperty("leaf")
```

Comment: tree.leaves may be undefined for me thats why i exactly needed how i asked

Comment: these attributes are dynamically created

Comment: As per my understanding, we need to check the respective property of the object.Here leaf is property of leaves object which comes under tree object

Comment: Please check here once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a property with key `leaves.leaf`, then you need to use bracket notation

```
tree["leaves.leaf"]={}
```

now `tree.hasOwnProperty("leaves.leaf")` will give `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is recursive function that get deep props from object with dot notation:

```
export function getDeepProp(_object: any, path: string) {
    const deepRef: any = (obj: any, path: any) => {
        if (path.length == 1) return obj[path];

        const currItem = path.shift();
        return obj[currItem] ? deepRef(obj[currItem], path) : undefined;
    }

    return deepRef(_object, path.split('.'));
}
```

Using case:

```
const props = {
  options: {
     maxWidth: 100
  }
}

getDeepProp(props, "options.maxWidth")
```